# How to use SIFR or Facelift with ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, sifr, image-manipulation

Has anyone used SIFR or Facelift (FLIR) with ASP.net? I noticed that all the scripts included with FLIR are all PHP pages. I looked around but it looks like there isn't a good solution for image replacement for ASP.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sIFR is a client-side technique that leverages Javascript and Flash, so is pretty much independent of which server-side language you use. For some examples of how to implement it, see [How to use](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/How+to+use).

Answer (score 0):

Either go for the client side solution sIFR.

Or if you want to do it server side, rewrite the PHP into ASP.NET, or install PHP on your server.